# Combine multiple logical operators

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there a way to combine parameters for multiple logical operators in a where statement?

Basically I have a statement like this:

```
<command chain> | where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "USER1" -and $_.user.tostring() -ne "USER2" -and $_.user.tostring() -ne "USER3"}
```

It's actually a fairly long chain, so I'd like to simplify it so that it becomes something like this:

```
<command chain> | where {$_.user.tostring() -ne {"USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3"}}
```

The above statement doesn't work, so any suggestions please on how to go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use this:

```
where {$_.user.tostring() -notin ("USER1","USER2","USER3")}
```

Or this:

```
where {($_.user.tostring() -ne "USER1") -and ($_.user.tostring() -ne "USER2") -and ($_.user.tostring() -ne "USER3") }
```

That's really about as simple as you can get.  The boolean operators should, in general, only be used to combine comparison operators (or other things you know represent boolean values).

---

Your code here:

```
where {$_.user.tostring() -ne {"USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3"}}
```

This is basically nonsense.  It's always going to evaluate to true.  `{"USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3"}` is of datatype ScriptBlock.

```
PS C:\> ({"USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3"}).GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock
```

I believe PowerShell will cast this to a string, but even if it gets cast to a string, it's still not evaluated as a boolean expression:

```
PS C:> ({"USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3"}).ToString()
"USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3"
```

That's going to evaluate to True unless the user is literally '"USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3"'

If you changed it so that it was a parenthetic expression instead of a script block:

```
where {$_.user.tostring() -ne ("USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3")}
```

Then it would always be true.  `("USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3")` is of type Boolean, and will always have the value of true.

```
PS C:\> ("USER1" -or "USER2" -or "USER3")
True
```

So you're basically running:

```
where {$_.user.tostring() -ne $true }
```

Again, even if PowerShell converts everything to a string like I think it will, it's pretty unlikely you've got a user named "True".  So this will always be true.

Comment: Note that uniquely in powershell,, -and and -or have equal precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dealing with a array it can be done in this similar fashion you wrote it, even shorter check this out:

```
PS Z:\> @("food","drink","cheese","dog") -match "(food|cheese)"
food
cheese

PS Z:\> @("food","drink","cheese","dog") -notmatch "(food|cheese)"
drink
dog

where clause:

PS Z:\> @("food","drink","cheese","dog") | where {$_ -notmatch "(food|cheese)"}
drink
dog
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [About Comparison Operators / Common features](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features)

> When the input of an operator is a scalar value, the operator returns
> a Boolean value. When the input is a collection, the operator returns
> the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the
> expression. If there are no matches in the collection, comparison
> operators return an empty array. For example:

```
<command chain> | where {"USER1", "USER2", "USER3" -ne $_.user.tostring()}
```